# When does AWS CloudWatch create new log streams?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

AWS CloudWatch has Log Groups and Log streams. A log group seems reasonable to me: Each product (e.g. each Lambda function, each Sagemaker endpoint) has its own log group.

But then there are log streams. **When does AWS CloudWatch create new log streams?** Can I search all log streams of a log group?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [AWS Cloudwatch documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html) you can see that a log stream is created each time the logs come from a different event source. In case of Lambda, it's one stream per Lambda container where each container might process multiple events.

> A log stream is a sequence of log events that share the same source. Each separate source of logs into CloudWatch Logs makes up a separate log stream.

Yes, you can search all log streams of a log group using the CloudWatch Logs API. The [FilterLogEvents action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_FilterLogEvents.html) allows you to search through a log group.

Comment: "In case of Lambda, each new request represents a new event source, thus a new log stream is created."

Not accurate: it's one stream per Lambda container where each container might process multiple events.

Comment: Thanks @Dunedan I've amended the answer

Comment: What exactly is a lambda container? Is it the same as a lambda function? I have the impression, every time I click on "test" it creates a new log stream. But it definitely does not create a new log stream each time the lambda function is invoked.

Comment: Lambda functions are executed in containers. Concurrent requests of the same lambda function will be executed in the same container. When there are no more requests to execute a lambda function, the container will be terminated.

Comment: Did you know how many time to generate log of CloudWatch Log? i think sometimes the log generates delay but don't know exactly the range time of it.

Comment: Concurrent means "at the same time". Concurrent requests of the same lambda function will be executed in **different** containers, not the same container at all. Each container handles exactly one request at a time. **Sequential** requests *might* be handled by the same container. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/