# How can I make all log entries within each 5-minute interval appear in the same log stream for an AWS CDK REST API?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have created a REST API using the AWS CDK and specified the following for the access logs:

```js
const apiLogGroup = new cdk.aws_logs.LogGroup(this, `${this.apiName}-logGroup`, {
  retention: cdk.aws_logs.RetentionDays.ONE_MONTH,
  logGroupName: `/aws/apigateway/${this.apiName}`,
});

const accessLogDestination = new apigw.LogGroupLogDestination(apiLogGroup);
const accessLogFormat = apigw.AccessLogFormat.custom(
  JSON.stringify({
    requestId: apigw.AccessLogField.contextRequestId(),
    email: apigw.AccessLogField.contextAuthorizer('email'),
    path: apigw.AccessLogField.contextResourcePath(),
    method: apigw.AccessLogField.contextHttpMethod(),
  })
);

new apigw.RestApi(this, this.apiName, {
  deployOptions: {
    accessLogDestination,
    accessLogFormat,
  }
});
```

However I get dozens of new logstreams every second which contain only a single log. I would like to have all logs of say a 5 minute interval in the same logstream. Is there a way to ensure that all log entries within each 5-minute interval end up in the same log stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  Which log stream a service writes to is not user-configurable, either with or without the CDK.  See this related question:  [When does AWS CloudWatch create new log streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48659141/when-does-aws-cloudwatch-create-new-log-streams).

Use the [FilterLogEvents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_FilterLogEvents.html) API or [LogInsights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html) to abstract away the log stream details if they are getting in your way.